# como exteneder una clase generica en java

Tags: java, genericos

Quiero tener una clase en la que poder indicar que clase extiende.
Algo como

```
public class ComunAux extends T {
    private MyObject obj
    [...]
}
```

No me vale lo contrario: que una clase extienda ComunAux y así tener ese campo MyObject

También me podría valer que la clase ComunAux tenga un campo de tipo T, algo como:

```
public class ComunAux<T> {
    private T parent;
    [... otros campos comunes ...]
 }
```

Pero en este último caso, ¿cómo creo la instancia de parent en el constructor de ComunAux?

IMPORTANTE: trabajo con Java 6 (1.6.0_45)

EDITO, ante las dudas...

En el segundo caso, en el constructor por defecto, sin parámetros, de `ComunAux`, necesitaría inicializar el atributo `T parent` para que no sea null, es decir algo así (sé que está mal): `this.parent = new T()`, porque esto lo voy a usar en una consulta Hibernate y no puedo usar el constructor que quiera (o eso creo)

¿Porqué necesito esto?
Tengo que obtener de base de datos, con Hibernate, una lista de objectos (A), entre los datos obtenidos hay toda una entity (vamos a llamarla X) que no quiero dejar en la lista final, sino que en su lugar dejo un String que contiene la concatenación de diversos campos de X (con una lógica especial de concatenación).
Para resolver esto creo una clase auxiliar con el campo X y que extienda A para que tenga todos los datos de A:

```
class Aaux extends A {
    X x;
    //get/set de x
}
```

Con `Aaux` hago la consulta, obteniendo un `List<Aaux> listaAux`.
Recorro todo `listaAux`, configurando el campo A.xx a partir del Aaux.X que he obtenido creo una nueva lista `List<A> result`:

```
List<A> result = new ....;
    for(Aaux itemAux: listaAux){
        itemAux.setX(concatenarX(itemAux.x);
        result.add(itemAux); 
        //aqui ya me quedo solo con los datos de A, sin X
    }
return result;
```

Ahora tengo que repetir esto en 3 casos más, cada uno con una entity distinta: B, C y D. Por lo que tendría que crear sus correspondiente clases auxiliares, todas con el mismo campo X pero extendiendo una clase distinta:
class Baux extends B
class Caux extends C
...

Mi objetivo es tener una sola clase auxiliar a la que le pueda indicar cual es su clase padre en el momento de usarla.

Y para el que no sepa hibernate... debo indicar la clase (class) a devolver, es decir `Aaux.class`, o `ComunAux<A>.class` (como se tenga que hacer)

A lo mejor pido lo imposible :(

Gracias por las respuesta e intentarlo :)

Comment: No tengo ni idea de qué es lo que quieres hacer. Se indica que una clase extiende de otra con `extends`. Y ¿qué es "la instancia de parent en el constructor"? ¿Puedes explicarte mejor?

Comment: Esto parece el clásico [*problema XY*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Sería mejor que en lugar de pedirnos cómo hacer la herramienta, nos digas qué trabajo quieres hacer con ella. Los que estás pidiendo no tiene mucho sentido

Answer (score 2):

Empezaremos por lo que tienes bien.

> A lo mejor pido lo imposible :(

Correcto.

Ahora vamos con lo demás.

> Mi objetivo es tener una sola clase auxiliar a la que le pueda indicar cual es su clase padre en el momento de usarla.

En programación (en general en todos los campos técnicos) hay que hablar con propiedad. La clase padre es la que se indica en el `extends` y **no se puede cambiar una vez compilada**.

> En el segundo caso, en el constructor por defecto, sin parámetros, de ComunAux, necesitaría inicializar el atributo T parent para que no sea null, es decir algo así (sé que está mal): this.parent = new T(),

No se puede.

La información de *generics* está disponible solo **en tiempo de compilación**. Los *generics* son un truco para que la gente no hiciera cosas como éstas:

```
List listaStrings = new ArrayList();
listaStrings.add(new Integer(5));
String miString = (String) listaStrings.get(0);
```

(obviamente, es mucho más complicado cuando introduces en la lista en veinte sitios distintos y tienes que repasarlos todos buscando el bug).

Pero a nivel de binarios no se podía meter esta información sin introducir incompatibilidades con los binarios compilados para JVMs anteriores, y eso en Java no gusta mucho, así que se decidió que no se incluiría esa información.

A nivel de binarios, el código anterior es idéntico a:

```
List<Object> listaStrings = new ArrayList<>();
listaStrings.add(new Integer(5));
String miString = (String) listaStrings.get(0);
```

y al que saldría si te dejara compilar:

```
List<String> listaStrings = new ArrayList<>();
listaStrings.add(new Integer(5));
String miString = listaStrings.get(0);
```

Eso se denomina *[type erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure)*. Así que en tiempo de ejecución, no sabes qué es "T".

Sobre lo que intentas (o lo que creo que intentas hacer, lo he leído como seis o siete veces y aún no lo tengo claro)<sup>1</sup>, una opción sería.

```
public interface Concatenable {
  String concatenar();
}

public class A implements Concatenable {
  protected String concatenar() { //Tu implementación de concatenar 
  }
}
```

Y luego una clase auxiliar (**que no tiene porqué extender de A, o B**) con el método que toma un `List<Concatenable>` y lo procesa.

En todo caso, mi consejo es en general evitar "trucos" e "historias raras" solo para evitar escribir un par de métodos; la mantenibilidad y el principio de mínima sorpresa son mucho más importantes. Recuerda que la herencia significa acoplamiento fuerte y más dificultades de mantenimiento, hay que usarla solo cuando tiene sentido y aparece naturalmente. Se recomienda en general usar composición.

---

<sup>1</sup>Lo he dicho justo arriba, pero lo repito. Evita las "genialidades".

Comment: Gracias Sjuan76. Muchas gracias por tanto detalle. Aprendida la lección: abandono está "genialidad" que de me ocurrió ;)

Answer (score 0):

En la clase genérica debes pasar en el constructor un objeto del mismo tipo que definiste la genérica, y como verás puedes definir otras propiedades como aquí puse un string llamado otraCosa.

Como no sabes que objeto es el que llegó en tu constructor ya que es genérico, la única forma de obtener propiedades de el mismo es con reflexión, de ese modo aquí recibo el nombre de la propiedad que quieres obtener y la intenta leer del objeto genérico T con el método getPropertyOfT

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Generic1<T> {

    private T obj;

    public Generic1(T obj){
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void classType() {
        System.out.println("El tipo de T es " + obj.getClass().getName());
    }

    public Object getPropertyOfT(String name) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
      Field field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);    
      field.setAccessible(true);
      Object value = field.get(obj);
      return value;
    }

    private String otraCosa = "hola";

    public String get_otraCosa() {
        return otraCosa;
    }

    public void set_otraCosa(String otraCosa) {
        this.otraCosa = otraCosa;
    }
}
```

Suponiendo que tenemos cualquier otro objeto en este caso tengo este llamado Principal con una sola propiedad llamada valor

```
public class Principal {

    private int valor = 5;

    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

El llamado de la clase genérica sería de la siguiente forma, y así podrías obtener propiedades ya sea de la clase genérica o de la clase tipo T

```
public class Ejemplo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generic1<Principal> g = new Generic1<Principal>(new Principal());
        System.out.println(g.get_otraCosa());
        try {
            System.out.println(g.getPropertyOfT("valor"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es una respuesta muy trabajada, pero deberías haberte esperado a que el OP aclarase qué quiere conseguir. Es una forma un poco rebuscada de hacer las cosas y seguramente (viendo la falta de base en los conceptos de POO) el problema tenga una solución más simple

Comment: gracias shop350, pero necesito inicializar el atributo en el constructor por defecto